# How to load the another page on ajax success function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need to load the another page on ajax success function .

I have two files namely `file1` and `file2`. On `file1` ajax success function load  `file2`.

Comment: `location.href = 'http://example.com/newurl';`

Comment: If you're going to redirect immediately after the completion of the AJAX request there is no point in having an AJAX request.

Comment: Are you loading a whole other page or just HTML content generated by file2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in javascript for redirect use

```
window.location.href ="http://google.com";
```

or in jquery use `.load()`

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html" );
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

You can use **iframe** to load any another page content.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan..Please have a look with answer of wayzz...by using iframe..can you please tell is that not possible?

Comment: Scenario: one page have two section...one section has Yes and No button and another section has Iframe which has default page loaded for No button...if user click on Yes button then on ajax success (necessary operation done) it will load iframe with require page..will Iframe not useful in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Create an iframe and give it css '`display:none;`'. Then when calling the ajax in the success function do:

```
$('iframe').attr('src', yoururl)
$('iframe').show();
```